# How can I get the rows with specific elements in dataset

Tags: dataset, column, row

[image]

As you can see from the picture, I want to get the rows in a14 that contains all of the a15 elements in them. By the way a15 is a part of the 1st column of a14.

```
Hyperlink["https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-history.csv"]


a14=PrependTo[a13, a12] // Transpose // Dataset


a15=List /@ Intersection[a12, key]
```

Comment: What are `key`, `a12`, `a13`? It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: isd = Import[
   "D:/week/Introduction to Data Science/Final \
project/OneDrive_1_2021-2-27/isd-history.csv", "Data"] // Dataset; usaf = isd[[All, 1]] // Normal; wban = isd[[All, 2]] // Normal; usafwban = Thread[usaf -> wban]; a12 = StringReplace[ToString /@ usafwban, "->" -> ""]; a13 = isd // Normal // Transpose

Comment: key is the 1st column of the other dataset which is similar to a14, I want to find their intersection. And return the rows of a14 that only contain their intersection.